# NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault() does not contains definition in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

I am trying to get the last page in the navigation using the following in WP8

```
var lastPage = NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();
```

However Visual Studio 12 complaints that it does not contain a definition for `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file.